# Is it possible to have multiple @StreamListener in Spring Cloud Stream?

Tags: apache-kafka-streams, spring-cloud-stream

I using Spring cloud strema Kstream.
I test one topic & one `@StreamListner`. It's Ok.

I modify my code for two KStream Input. (two `@StreamListener`)
But, spring cloud error..

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

The bean 'stream-builder-process', defined in null, could not be registered. A bean with that name has already been defined in null and overriding is disabled.

Action:

Consider renaming one of the beans or enabling overriding by setting spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true


Process finished with exit code 1
```

#### First Listener

```java
    package com.kstream.spring.cloud.test1;

    import static com.kstream.spring.cloud.test1.MyBinding.TOPIC1_IN;

    import org.apache.avro.generic.GenericRecord;
    import org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.KStream;
    import org.springframework.cloud.stream.annotation.Input;
    import org.springframework.cloud.stream.annotation.StreamListener;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

    @Component
    public class Topic1Source {

      @StreamListener
      public void process(@Input(TOPIC1_IN) KStream<String, GenericRecord> logs) {

        logs
            .foreach((key, value) -> {
              System.out.println("Test Topic1 : " + value);
            });
      }
    }
```

Only **First Listener** is OK.

#### Second Listener

```java
    package com.kstream.spring.cloud.test1;

    import static com.kstream.spring.cloud.test1.MyBinding.TOPIC2_IN;

    import org.apache.avro.generic.GenericRecord;
    import org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.KStream;
    import org.springframework.cloud.stream.annotation.Input;
    import org.springframework.cloud.stream.annotation.StreamListener;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

    @Component
    public class Topic2Source {

      @StreamListener
      public void process(@Input(TOPIC2_IN) KStream<String, GenericRecord> logs) {

        logs
            .foreach((key, value) -> {
              System.out.println("Test Topic2 : " + value);
            });
      }
    }
```

But it's error

#### application.properties

```
spring.application.name=kafka-streams-test
spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers=my brokers

# defaults
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.binder.brokers=my brokers
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.binder.configuration.commit.interval.ms=1000
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.binder.configuration.schema.registry.url=my server


# topic1
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.topic1In.destination=topic1
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.topic1In.consumer.useNativeDecoding=true
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.topic1In.consumer.header-mode=raw
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.bindings.topic1In.consumer.keySerde=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes$StringSerde
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.bindings.topic1In.consumer.valueSerde=io.confluent.kafka.streams.serdes.avro.SpecificAvroSerde




# topic2
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.topic2In.destination=topic2
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.topic2In.consumer.useNativeDecoding=true
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.topic2In.consumer.header-mode=raw
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.bindings.topic2In.consumer.keySerde=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes$StringSerde
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.bindings.topic2In.consumer.valueSerde=io.confluent.kafka.streams.serdes.avro.SpecificAvroSerde
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I find error reason.
Because I defined two same method name of 'process'.

Comment: Glad you were able to find that out. We just filed an issue to address that problem: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/issues/589

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide separate application id's for both inputs. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54524930/2070861) issue and the answer.

Comment: I add separate application id' for both inputs. But it's also not working with same error messege..

Answer (score 0):

I modify pom.xml version. It's working. But This version not use application id's propertity.

```xml
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <!--<version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>-->
        <version>2.0.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>


    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <!--<spring-cloud.version>Greenwich.SR1</spring-cloud.version>-->
        <spring-cloud.version>Finchley.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>
```

#### spring-boot-starter-parent version

- 2.1.3.RELEASE => Error
- 2.0.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT => Working

#### spring-cloud.version

- Greenwich.SR1 => Error
- Finchley.BUILD-SNAPSHOT => Working

I don't understand why latest version is not working.

Comment: But it's also not expected working. Because It's only working one StreamListener.

Comment: Can you provide a sample application on GH where it fails? That way we will reproduce it on our end and see whats wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think you could give a try that changing the "logs" to "logs2" for the second listener.

Thanks,
Du